# Add total rows from groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Currently my csv looks like this:

| title | field1 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | A11 | 553 |
| A | A1 | A12 | 94 |
| A | A1 | A13 | 30 |
| A | A2 | A21 | 200 |
| A | A3 | A31 | 35 |

But I am wanting it to look like this:

| title | field1 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | A11 | 553 |
| A | A1 | A12 | 94 |
| A | A1 | A13 | 30 |
| A | A1 | total | 657 |
| A | A2 | A21 | 200 |
| A | A2 | total | 200 |
| A | A3 | A31 | 35 |
| A | A3 | total | 35 |

This is my code:

```
def fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order):
    df = df.groupby(['field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)\
                .agg(cols_to_aggregate)
    df['title'] = 'A'
    df = df[cols_order]
    return df


def create_csv(df, month_date):
    cols_to_aggregate = {'field3': 'sum'}
    cols_order = ['title', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3']
    funCSV = fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order)
    return funCSV
```

Any help would be appreciated as I can't figure out how to add the new row to the table. I tried this:

```
total = df.groupby('field2')['field3'].sum()
```

But it just adds the numbers to the end of the table instead of integrating them in the table with the relevant other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with sorting by both columns with aggregate DataFrame:

```
def fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order):
    df = df.groupby(['field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)\
                .agg(cols_to_aggregate)
    total = df.groupby('field1', as_index=False)['field3'].sum().assign(field2='total')
    df = pd.concat([df, total]).sort_values(['field1','field2'], ignore_index=True)
    df['title'] = 'A'

    print (df)
    df = df[cols_order]
    return df
```

Comment: The first line `df = df.groupby(['field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)\
                .agg(cols_to_aggregate)` actually creating another DataFrameGroupBy object, not a dataframe. I am not sure what is the type of cols_to_aggregate. Is it the column name (e.g. field3 in this example) or a dictionary?